# Parse text using PowerShell and a regex

Tags: regex, powershell-5.0

Parse text using PowerShell and a regex:

Find `"display_name":"elocin_anagram"` and output `elocin_anagram`. Repeat for all `"display_name:...."`.

How would you do it?

There should be no file named `1.txt` in your temp folder.

```
# set-content of text file
sc $env:temp\1.txt '_total":19,"subscriptions":[{"created_at":"2018-06-15T19:34:38Z","_id":"b7c42f6ce857162220e99533d3d6dc1ae11fac8d","sub_plan":"3000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub (❤ω❤)♡ ♡ ♡(elocin_anagram)","is_gift":false,"user":{"display_name":"elocin_anagram","type":"user","bio":"Games I like to play are VRChat, Beat Saber, Space Engineers, and Apex. I am also a certified Electronics Technician. You might see me make electronics and 3d model.","created_at":"2015-06-17T05:37:38Z","updated_at":"2020-05-11T05:51:58Z","name":"elocin_anagram","_id":"93742615","logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d37d128b-59b1-4015-9776-74866feb1d44-profile_image-300x300.png"},"sender":null},{"created_at":"2019-07-10T00:04:45Z","_id":"6a26c5a56b39d142a6e25ad30589a1b923fbc1bb","sub_plan":"1000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub(≧◡≦) ♡ (elocin_anagram) ","is_gift":false,"user":{"display_name":"LuckeaterVR","type":"user","bio":"","created_at":"2018-12-08T04:55:48Z","updated_at":"2020-04-24T01:44:56Z","name":"luckeatervr","_id":"00000","logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/322ba52a-655c-42a4-8cc9-7b875debd5dd-profile_image-300x300.png"},"sender":null},{"created_at":"2020-01-16T01:23:17Z","_id":"17704f74767b5592c5fc221eca11a20579a8162c","sub_plan":"3000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub (❤ω❤)♡ ♡'
(gc $env:temp\1.txt | select-string '"display_name":"(.*?)"' -AllMatches).Matches.Value | % {$_ -match '"display_name":"(.*?)"' > $null; $matches[1]}
#
```

Results:

```
elocin_anagram
LuckeaterVR
```

Comment: Hi, I's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @JPBlanc - A code review or alternatives to `(gc $env:temp\1.txt | select-string '"display_name":"(.*?)"' -AllMatches).Matches.Value | % {$_ -match '"display_name":"(.*?)"' > $null; $matches[1]}`

Answer (score 2):

You may greatly simplify the code if you use a regex with a positive lookbehind:

```
gc $file |select-string '(?<="display_name":")[^"]+' -AllMatches | Select-Object -Expand Matches | %{ $_.Value }
```

Here, `(?<="display_name":")[^"]+` matches a location that is immediately preceded with `"display_name":"` and then matches and consumes (i.e. places in the matched text memory buffer) one or more chars other than `"`. So, you do not need to access Group 1, the result is in Group 0, the match value.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%22display_name%22%3A%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D%2B&i=%E2%99%A1%28elocin_anagram%29%22%2C%22is_gift%22%3Afalse%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22display_name%22%3A%22elocin_anagram%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22bio%22%3A%22Games%20I%20like%20to%2074866feb1d44-profile_image-300x300.png%22%7D%2C%22sender%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22created_at%22%3A%222019-07-10T00%3A04%3A45Z%22%2C%22_id%22%3A%226a26c5a56b39d142a6e25ad30589a1b923fbc1bb%22%2C%22sub_plan%22%3A%221000%22%2C%22sub_plan_name%22%3A%22Channel%20Sub%28%E2%89%A7%E2%97%A1%E2%89%A6%29%20%E2%99%A1%20%28elocin_anagram%29%20%22%2C%22is_gift%22%3Afalse%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22display_name%22%3A%22LuckeaterVR%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22bio%22%3A%22%22%2C%22created_at%22%3A%222018-12-08T04%3A55%3A48Z%22%2C%22updated_at%22%3A%222020-04-).